# Static assets in play java

Tags: scala, playframework, static-assert

I have save path in database, when I use it in view

```
@for(photo <- photos){
        <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/photo.getPath()")" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
 }
```

photo.getPath() is not working, I try with @photo.getPath() still not working. Any suggest for me. I use play-java version 2.5. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I find the Twirl syntax a bit unintuitive. The `@` marks the start of a scala statement. The length of this statement is determined automatically.

Now looking at the `img` tag:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/photo.getPath()")" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

the following piece of code should be identified as a single statement:

```
routes.Assets.versioned("images/photo.getPath()")
```

From a scala point of view, the `"images/photo.getPath()"` is just a `String`. It will not execute any method on the `photo` object.  I think (I didn't test this) that your issue should be solveable by replacing this part by `s"images/${photo.getPath()}"`. Note that the [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) will make sure that the method on the `photo` object will be called.

This would make your example look like:

```
@for(photo <- photos) {
    <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned(s"images/${photo.getPath()}")" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
}
```

Comment: Additionally (and off topic), I believe that the `img` tag should be self-closing. So you might want to change it to: `<img src="..." ... />`

Comment: Thank for answer, resolved with: `@for(photo <- photos){
           <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned(s"images/${photo.getPath()}")" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
          }`